# SQL to select multiple date fields in range

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a SQL statement that select records by filtering multiple date fields in same row for a date range, Any date field that falls under the supplied start or end data then it should display from the table below
Actually I am planning to write as SQL Command in Crystal and therefore the values for StartDate and EndDate and Country and City will be supplied to this SQL Statement. So, dont bother about the crystal report at this moment. Its just how do I handle this in SQL Select statement?
Any ideas???

parameters are: StartDate and EndDate, Country AND/OR City

SQL:

```
Select * from Table where
ActualStart in StartDate and EndDate
Or 
ActualEnd in StartDate and EndDate
or
ProjectedStart in StartDate and EndDate
or ProjectedEnd in StartDate and EndDate
AND
County = CountyParam AND (if Not Null(CityParam) then City = CityParam)
```

DATA:

```
WORKID  Country CITY      Cost   ActualStart  ActualEnd ProjectedStart  ProjectedEnd 
18112   US      BOSTON    0        NULL         NULL      4/25/2017      NULL
18181   US      BOSTON    566.76  6/1/2016     6/6/2017   6/6/2017       NULL
18183   GERMANY STUTTGART  0       NULL         NULL      6/6/2017       NULL
18184   GERMANY MUNICH     0       NULL        6/6/2017   6/6/2017       NULL
18185   INDIA   HYDERABAD  0      4/1/2015      NULL      7/6/2017       NULL
18186   CANADA  TORONTO    0       NULL         NULL      4/6/2017       NULL
18187   CANADA  TORONTO    0      1/1/2016      NULL      3/6/2017       NULL
18188   CANADQ  CALGARY    0       NULL         NULL      6/6/2017   6/6/2018
18189   US      BOSTON     0       NULL         NULL      6/6/2017       NULL
18190   US      CHICAGO  1429.76   NULL        6/7/2017   6/7/2017       NULL
18191   US      NEWYORK    0       NULL         NULL      8/7/2017       NULL
```

Comment: just use `BETWEEN` i.e. `WHERE (ActualStart BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate) OR (ActualEnd BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate) OR ...`

Comment: If StartDate or EndDate can be NULL, use COALESCE(StartDate, '1900-01-01') for StartDate and COALESCE(EndDate, '2100-01-01') for EndDate.

Comment: Seems a bit strange. Were you intending to exclude long-running items? With start date before the requested start date, and end date after the requested end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers
I was able to solve this by ideas from your answers, one by using  between syntax and also coalesce function and then finally added a SQL commands to Crystal with only Date parameters (From and To Date).
For the logic to handle Country and City, I used Select record in Crystal to add this as end statement to previous SQL. It works fine now.
Thanks